# Map SQL to class in Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper-extensions

My problem: When using this extension it only maps up the ID value from the database to class object.

So I'm curious how do i make it map the other values?

**C# Mapper**

```
 public class SoftwareReleaseTypeHandle : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<SoftwareRelease>
    {
        public override SoftwareRelease Parse(object value)
        {
            if (value == null || value is DBNull)
            {
                return null;
            }

            SoftwareRelease rel = new SoftwareRelease();
            rel.ID = (Guid)value;

            return rel;
        }

        public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, SoftwareRelease value)
        {
            parameter.DbType = DbType.Guid;
            parameter.Value = value.ID.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The SQL table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SoftwareRelease](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseType] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ZipFile] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The reason i used this mapper was so in other places in my code i could do, and it would automaticly get mapped up:

```
class MyInstallation
{
 public string Bla;
 public string BlaBla;
 SoftwareRelease MyInstallation;
}
```

And when i then use Dapper to get from a table that looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyInstallation](
        [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [Bl] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
        [BlaBla] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
        [MyInstallation] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper type handlers are intended to map a single column value in your database to a single member in your POCO. They are used for types that Dapper's core doesn't understand - generally anything that isn't a .NET core type.

You don't say exactly what you need to do but if you're just trying to read `SoftwareRelease` rows from the database then you can simply do the following:

```
myDb.Query<SoftwareRelease>("SELECT * FROM SoftwareRelease");
```

**Update**

Sounds like what you really want is [multi-mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping). If you have the following query:

```
SELECT a.Bla, a.BlaBla, b.*
FROM MyInstallation a
INNER JOIN SoftwareRelease b ON a.SoftwareReleaseId = b.ID
```

Then you can use the following to populate the object:

```
myDB.Query<MyInstallation, SoftwareRelease, MyInstallation>(
    sql, 
    (installation, softwareRelease) => {
        installation.SoftwareRelease = softwareRelease;
    });
```

Comment: Added more from the usage. But its basicly so i get a SoftwareRelease class object from the Referense GUID in other tables.

But when i added this, i basicly broke that its unable to get SoftwareRelease class